# firewalld Zone "trusted" Drops about 15% of Frames that are Passed by Zone "public"

Tags: linux, networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, firewalld, iperf

### Background

I have two lab machines, which I'll refer to as **A** and **B**, running **RHEL 8.0**.

I SSH into **A** and **B** from my Windows desktop over a 1 GbE link, whose network interface I'll refer to as **eth0**.

**A** and **B** also have a direct 10 GbE fiber link between them (directly connected, no switches or routers involved). I'll refer to this link's network interface as **eth1**. The IP addresses of these 10 GbE network interfaces on **A** and **B** are **192.168.0.1/24** and **192.168.0.2/24**, respectively.

I am using **iperf3 v3.5** to test unidirectional (B --> A) **UDP** throughput. The MTU is set to 1500, and each frame's payload is 1500 bytes so that the frames are as large as they can be without fragmentation.

With **firewalld** stopped, I get throughput of about **7.00 Gbps** and **no frame drops**.

If I start **firewalld**, put **eth1** into zone **public**, and add the appropriate UDP port (5201) to zone **public**, I get throughput of about **6.43 Gbps** and **no frame drops**.

However, if I put **eth1** into zone **trusted** (which passes all traffic without question), I start seeing **massive frame drops (about 15%)**.

On both **A** and **B**, CPU 18 is isolated so that it is available for exclusive use by **iperf3**.

**iperf3** server invocation (on **A**) is:

```
taskset -c 18 iperf3 -s -V --udp-counters-64bit
```

**iperf3** client invocation (on **B**) is:

```
taskset -c 18 iperf3 -u -V -b 0 --udp-counters-64bit -t 120 -c 191.168.0.1 -l 1472
```

### My Question

Why do I see a large number of frames dropped when using **firewalld** zone **trusted** (as opposed to **public**, which works fine)?

### Additional Notes Based on Comments Received

**COMMENT**

*Is iperf3 or firewalld hitting 100% cpu usage on that core? Have you tried using dpdk-iperf? Do you get this behavior in reverse too, from A->B? – Cpt.Whale*

**RESPONSE**

When using zone **public**, **iperf3** runs at about **88%** CPU utilization on the receiving side and at about **95%** CPU utilization on the sending side.

When using zone **trusted**, **iperf3** runs at about **94%** CPU utilization on the receiving side and at about **95%** CPU utilization on the sending side. However... When using zone **trusted**, there is another high-CPU-utilization process on the receiving side named **ksoftirqd**. It runs on a different core and saturates that core at **100%** CPU utilization.

**firewalld** does not consume enough CPU to appear in the list.

I have not tried **dpdk-iperf**.

Yes, the same behavior occurs in the reverse direction. (The hardware and configuration are identical, so this is expected.)

Comment: Is iperf3 or firewalld hitting 100% cpu usage on that core? Have you tried using dpdk-iperf? Do you get this behavior in reverse too, from A->B?

Comment: Hi, Cpt.Whale. I have edited my original post to include responses to your questions.